# Java String charset parsing

Tags: java, character-encoding

I'm parsing some webpages using the Jsoup API. But I get the pages in 1 charset and have to parse them to other

The problem: How to parse line 1 into line 2?

```
String str1 = "Um grupo ligado &agrave; al-Qaeda assumiu o "
    + "ataque e amea&ccedil;ou fazer outros.";

String str2 = "Um grupo ligado &#224; al-Qaeda assumiu o "
    + "ataque e amea&#231;ou fazer outros.";

//(The text above translate to some news about WTC)
```

Comment: This isn't a UTF-8 to ASCII transformation.

Comment: UTF-8 ≠ named character entities.  ASCII ≠ numeric character references.

Comment: I'm only seeing the named entities replaced by numeric ones - is this what you actually need?

Comment: I need to parse a to b. I'm srry if I got the names confused. I tried 3 or 4 different sollutions I saw, and nothing worked.

Comment: Or is there a problem typing into the SO editor?  Perhaps your initial data shows and actual à and an actual ç and you want to generate numeric entities.  But there is no such thing as unencoded text.  What actuall _is_ the incoming character encoding?

Comment: @RayToal, str1 and str2 are the simplest examples I could think of. They come as str1, and I like to get them to be like str2. I just couldn figured it out by mysel so far..

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on the subject, but I believe that the answer you are seeking is at http://www.davidcraddock.net/tag/beautifulsoup/

Answer (score 0):

I have not really tested [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) but [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) has been very helpful to me when I needed to convert HTML to XML using the class `org.w3c.tidy.Tidy`. This automatically converts the entities.

```
static String str1 = "Um grupo ligado &agrave; al-Qaeda assumiu o "
        + "ataque e amea&ccedil;ou fazer outros.";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(cleanData(str1));
}

private static String cleanData(String data) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
    tidy.setNumEntities(true); // to num entities
    tidy.setPrintBodyOnly(true); // only print the content
    tidy.setWraplen(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // wrap
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    tidy.parseDOM(inputStream, outputStream);
    return outputStream.toString("UTF-8");
}
```

You can also get an instance of `Document` if you wish.

```
public org.w3c.dom.Document parseDOM(Reader in, Writer out)
public org.w3c.dom.Document parseDOM(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
```

Comment: I have added your `str1`. Removed input encoding. And specify the output with numbered entities.

Answer (score 0):

A bit like the JTidy solution: the named entities, like `&agrave;` are defined in .dtd files at w3c.org which maintains the HTML `<!DOCTYPE ...`s. Copy them locally and parse them (easy). Then you can either immediately substitute the entity by unicode strings, or make numeric entities.